# Convert String to HashMap/MultiSet?

Tags: java, split, hashmap, multiset

What is the best way to convert a long string to a data structure with words and counts.

I would do .split(" ") to split on spaces and presumably make an arraylist, then maybe go through arraylist and add each item to a hashmap or multiset? I'm not sure what the best way to do this is/if it can be done directly with some sort of hashmap without making an arraylist first.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what your data looks like ?

Comment: just lots and lots of strings, something like "word bla bla word another word /moren+!*&^@#random words"?

Comment: How do you define 'best'? as fast as possible, use as little memory as possible or easy to read and understand the code?

Comment: well i'm not too concerned about it being optimal any acceptable way is good? I'm just not sure what people usually do for such a common task. likely i'll make arraylist, then go through arraylist and add each item to hashmap with a count? then merge multiple hashmaps for different strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    private static Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addToCountMap("This is my test string and it contains Test and test and string and some more");
        addToCountMap("This is my test string and it contains Test and test and string and some more");
        addToCountMap("This is my test string and it contains Test and test and string and some more");
        addToCountMap("This is my test string and it contains Test and test and string and some more");
        addToCountMap("This is my test string and it contains Test and test and string and some more");

        mergeWithCountMap(count);

        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static void addToCountMap(String test) {
        String[] split = test.split(" ");
        for (String string : split) {
            if (!count.containsKey(string)) {
                count.put(string, 0);
            }
            count.put(string, count.get(string) + 1);
        }
    }

    private static void mergeWithCountMap(Map<String, Integer> mapToMerge) {
        for (String string : mapToMerge.keySet()) {
            if (!count.containsKey(string)) {
                count.put(string, 0);
            }
            count.put(string, count.get(string) + mapToMerge.get(string));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: count.put(sting, 1) if you want the actual number in count.

Comment: yup, that looks like what I want. My only followup question would be, how would I merge two hashmaps? I may need to do this for hashmaps from different sources

Comment: uh what do you mean, i'm not sure, i want the total number of occurences, so i guess we need to add 1 to the existing count?

Comment: When you find the first occurrence, you want to start the count at 1.

Comment: oh that line yup you'd put 1

Comment: @stark the first occurence is started at 1 in my example.

Comment: @daveychu - sorry. I assumed an 'else' for the increment but I see you don't have one.

Comment: thanks! that's quite helpful. but in some cases, what would be the best way of combining two maps (if I already have something in map form rather than string form)

Comment: @Lemonio added merge example.

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to a [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), this is just the one line

```
HashMultiset.create(
  Splitter.on(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE).omitEmptyStrings()
    .split(string));
```

Comment: interesting, this looks quite simple, though I may go with the other case to avoid a situation where someone using my code won't have guava